# Macro Stops Working After First Run - Run-time Error 2004 Application-defined or Object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to put together a macro that finds a name in a column header then copies that column if the header matches.

It works the first time I run it but when the pasted column is deleted and the macro is run again I get a

> Run-time Error 2004 Application-defined or Object-defined error

on this line:

```
Set sRange = Sheets("Data").Range("C1", Cells(1, LastCol))
```

Full code:

```
Sub Copy()

Dim Cell As Range, sRange As Range, Rng As Range

    LastCol = Sheets("Data").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Set sRange = Sheets("Data").Range("C1", Cells(1, LastCol))

            With sRange

                Set Rng = .Find(What:="Chennai", _
                                After:=.Cells(1), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                MatchCase:=False)

                    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then

                        Lastrow = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, Rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row

                            Sheets("Data").Range(Rng, Cells(Lastrow, Rng.Column)).Copy _
                                Destination:=Sheets("Summary").Range("A7")
                    End If
            End With
End Sub
```

Can anyone see the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cells(1, LastCol))` has no worksheet specified. Therfore it is the same as `ActiveSheet.Cells(1, LastCol))` and if `Sheets("Data")` is not the `ActiveSheet` this fails.

It should be

```
Set sRange = Worksheets("Data").Range("C1", Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, LastCol))
```

or even better

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

Set sRange = ws.Range("C1", ws.Cells(1, LastCol))
```

Also I recommend to use `Worksheets` for worksheets as `Sheets` can also contain chart sheets etc.

Same problem in the end where `Cells(Lastrow, Rng.Column)` has no worksheet specified:

```
ws.Range(Rng, ws.Cells(Lastrow, Rng.Column)).Copy _
                            Destination:=Worksheets("Summary").Range("A7")
```

---

Make sure you **never** have a `Cells`, `Range`, `Rows` or `Columns` object without a worksheet specified. Or Excel might take the wrong worksheet.

In the end I would do something like (note that all variables should be declared, use `Option Explicit`:

```
Option Explicit 

Public Sub Copy()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet 'source worksheet
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    Dim wsDest As Worksheet 'destination worksheet
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")

    Dim LastCol As Long
    LastCol = wsSrc.Cells(1, wsSrc.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim sRange As Range
    Set sRange = wsSrc.Range("C1", wsSrc.Cells(1, LastCol))

    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = sRange.Find(What:="Chennai", _
                          After:=sRange.Cells(1), _
                          LookIn:=xlValues, _
                          LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False)

    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = wsSrc .Cells(wsSrc.Rows.Count, Rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row

        wsSrc.Range(Rng, wsSrc.Cells(LastRow, Rng.Column)).Copy _
                                Destination:=wsDest.Range("A7")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Peh. Much appreciated.